# Stop element shifting when window is resized in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created simple HTML code using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. I divided a row using `col-md-4` and `col-md-8`. The background image from `col-md-8` get shifted down when I resize the window.

I have attached code from the HTML and CSS files.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Bootstrap Practice </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="tp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body background = "red">
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row" >
        <div  class="col-md-4 col-sx-4 col-lg-4 nopadding" style="height:100%; ">
            <p style="align:middle">  This  is  first column bg </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sx-8 col-lg-8 shutterstock_227863141 nopadding" style="height:100%; ">
            <p>  This  is  second column </p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css - file ::

```
.shutterstock_227863141{
width: 60%;
height: 500px; 
background-image: url(Learning_fun.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #464646;
}

.nopadding{
margin : 0 !important;
padding : 0 !important;
}
```

How can I keep the background image from `col-md-8` from getting shifted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

xs (for phones)
sm (for tablets)
md (for desktops)
lg (for larger desktops)

Your code didn't work because it doesn't have `col-sm-*` and you misspelled `col-xs-*`.

You can learn more here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp